# How to give !important in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hiding one div and showing another. But I can't hide first div when the second is block. I think that's because first is bootstrap and need to overwrite to display with `!important` to run `display: none;` correctly. But how can I use the it in Javascript.

```
function switchVisible() {
      if (document.getElementById('main-card')) {

          if (document.getElementById('main-card').style.display == 'none') {
              document.getElementById('main-card').style.display = 'block';
              document.getElementById('map').style.display = 'none';
          }
          else {
              document.getElementById('main-card').style.display = 'none';
              document.getElementById('map').style.display = 'block';
          }
      }
  }
```

I tried 'none !important' but that doesn't work.

Comment: `none !important` works. If it doesn't have the desired effect then something else is at play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Jquery much more simple. And it'll fix your problem.

```
$('body').on("click touchstart", "#Button1", function(e){
   $("#main-card, #map").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use inline css style by jquery:

```
$('body').on("click touchstart", "#Button1", function(e){
   $("#main-card).css("display","none");
});
```

inline css is nearly !import